# Input string from ostream buffer

Tags: c++, ostream, ns-3

I have a function that I do not have control on, it prints stream output only to ostream buffer.

```
Packet::PrintPacketTags (std::ostream &os);
```

How can I get what is in the `os` buffer and handle it as a string?

Comment: [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream).